# 2017 Year in Review

Tags: discussion

With the new year behind, I wanted to ask what are some topics of discussion that Academia has addressed this past year and should be summarized in a year in review. With this in mind, what are some possible topics that needs to be considered moving forward?

In my recent memory, I can think of the continued need to help new users become acquainted with the SE format, what’s on and off topic; or that cheating is still an issue even at the graduate level.

Comment: No issues I guess...